# Is serial unupvoting allowed and not detected by system?

Tags: support, voting

While going through [Rakesh Joshi's reputation tab](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/7853/rakesh-joshi?tab=reputation), i found that, he had lost 145 points on Nov11. It clearly looks like someone serially unupvoting his several posts. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

..........................................................

Now, i know 1.["What is meant by an un-upvote?"](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/652/what-is-meant-by-an-unupvote) and 2. serial voting not allowed and they are auto-detected by system.

In this case, however, the unupvoting was not reversed.

Hence the question: Is serial unupvoting allowed and not detected by system?

Comment: Serial Unupvoting is not detected by the system.

Comment: It's definitely not allowed.

Comment: I remember seeing voting corrected in his profile some days. Now, it is showing just -145' . I think there's a bug.. not sure about this.

Comment: Someone serially upvoted him a day before this happened. The next day, they were reversed. So, there is nothing wrong in it. Only problem is it didn't show voting corrected. That is the bug there.

Answer (score 3):

Serial unupvoting is not detected by the system. It is **against the rules* because it is targetted on a user not the content. The system only identifies serial upvoting and downvoting.

To quote relevant post [Are unupvotes serial voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199952/357396)

> The votes are un-upvotes, but they are voting behavior non the less. And they are targeted at specific users, not the content.
>
> As such this goes against the rules - *it is not allowed in any shape or form*.

The moderators can reverse unupvoting if flagged to their intervention. They will take appropriate action after investigating.

In this specific case, the posts were serially upvoted on November 10. The reversal script might have detected it and the votes were reversed. So,  the system is working fine. The only problem is that it should show "*Voting Corrected*" but it's not showing like that. Probably a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

On November 10

[image: Pic of reputation history on Nov 10]

On November 11

[image: Pic of reputation history Nov 11]

Comment: Actually what i said cannot be possible since upvotes are locked. See his updated question.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I remember seeing voting corrected in his profile some days. Now, it is showing just -145'