# Would moderators please look into serial unupvoting of my years-old questions/answers?

Tags: support, voting

"Votes are locked 5 minutes after vote is cast . Votes, that are cast, can be removed (either unupvoting or undownvoting) only when that particular question or answer is edited." is said to be the policy.

Lately, upvotes on my answers, (at least 10) some years old, have been retracted.

Looks like an organized harassment campaign.  They can downvote, delete, close etc. to give negative feedback.  But this action degrades HSE as a whole.

I request that moderators look into reversing these actions.  This feels like intellectual terrorism and if the perpetrators can be found, they need to be severely sanctioned.

> unupvote -10 Does Narasimha Avatara occur in Vishnu Purana? 5 hours ago
>
> unupvote -10 Among Hindu Kings who fought invaders how many were Siva worshipers? 5 hours ago
>
> unupvote -10 Have Nandi, Hanuman and Adisesha been declared to be Brahman? 6 hours ago
>
> unupvote -10 which traditions call god by derogatory terms to express love? 6 hours ago
>
> unupvote -10 Is the Padmanabhaswamy idol at Trivandrum represented as worshipping Siva linga?
> 6 hours ago

[image]

Comment: One can change vote anytime if the answer is edited after voting. But this serial unupvoting looks targeted.

Comment: I haven't edited these question/answers for years.  which means someone edited them to unupvote and their identity is ascertainable from the edit history of the question/answer.   @pandya

Comment: Well, suppose you wrote an answer 10 years ago at 2 PM and someone upvotes at 2:10 PM and then if answer is edited at 2:20 PM, the upvoter can change his/her upvote even after 10 years.

Comment: But still - I feel ambushed.  these are all from years back - some serious effort has gone in to identify upvotes of my content that are eligible for unupvoting.  In my opinion, this action reflects poorly on HSE @pandya  I am thinking of opening a "trust and safety" ticket at SE.

Comment: This once happened to a user on a different site- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd2LF.png). It was after he'd posted a [controversial meta-question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7276). It might be that you've annoyed someone somehow.

Comment: "It might be that you've annoyed someone somehow. – " @CDR understatement of the year.

Comment: A related post about serial unupvoting --- [Is serial unupvoting allowed and not detected by system?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1039/4732)

Comment: "It's definitely not allowed. – 
Keshav Srinivasan
Mod
 Dec 2, 2017 at 19:31"  May I expect remedial action @Pandya ?

Comment: @SK We, mods, can't figure out who casted votes. Have you already contacted SE?

Comment: I will contact SE only if the mods say categorically that they won't be able to reverse these unupvotes @Pandya  We have a statement from keshav that it is "definitely not allowed" - surely mods have the power to reverse these unupvotes?

Comment: Intellectual terrorism. Severly reprimanded... So someone removes his or her own vote for whatsoever reason should be punished ?

Comment: The serial unupvoting is continuing.  As expected, the mods won't do anything about it. One says "it looks targeted" another says "it is definitely not allowed".  Another day at HSE.

Comment: @SK Mods don't have any tools to detect serial unupvoting, but it is not easy to serial unupvote. It could be even coincidence or really some planned unupvoting. Either case, we Mods can't know as far i know.

Comment: Do a group of real posters have these old upvotes sitting around that they are unupvoting like a Chinese water torture - OR HAS SOMEONE HACKED THE SYSTEM and is randomly deleting old upvotes?  DO MODERATORS CARE ABOUT THE INTEGRITY OF HSE AT ALL ???????????? @Pandya

Answer (score -1):

Here are the unupvotes ALL MADE THIS MONTH

(1) Does Moksha Dharma Parva contain this alleged quotation from it?  Asked 4 years, 7 months ago Modified 1 year, 4 months ago

(2) Is there any instance of Shiva showing his vishwaroopa in the Mahabharata?  Asked 4 years, 6 months ago Modified 4 years, 1 month ago

(3) Does Narasimha Avatara occur in Vishnu Purana?Asked 5 years, 9 months ago Modified 5 years, 9 months ago

(4) Have Nandi,Hanuman and Adisesha been declared to be Brahman?Asked 1 year, 4 months ago Modified 1 year ago

(5) which traditions call god by derogatory terms to express love?Asked 5 years, 6 months ago Modified 5 years, 6 months ago

(6) Is the Padmanabhaswamy idol at Trivandrum represented as worshipping Siva linga?Asked 5 years, 7 months ago, Modified 6 months ago

(7) Did other Srivaishnavite teachers like Vedanta Desikan differ from Ramanuja on the caste system?Asked 13 days ago Modified 6 days ago

(8) Is there any historical evidence for persecution of vaishnavaites by kulothunga chola II?Asked 7 years, 3 months agoModified 5 years, 8 months ago

(9) What is the percentage of vaishnavite temples that have anya-devata worship? Asked 5 years, 7 months ago Modified 5 years, 7 months ago

(10) Is the proto-indo-european hypothesis consistent with the apaurusheyatva of vedas?Asked 5 years, 7 months ago,Modified 5 years, 3 months ago

(11) Do Hindu scriptures prescribe how dead bodies can be preserved for centuries? Asked 5 years, 9 months ago Modified 5 years, 9 months ago

(12)Is the notion of sattvik, tamasic and rajasic puranas genuine?Asked 5 years, 9 months ago Modified 3 years, 2 months ago

(13) Is the mahamrityunjaya mantra the same mantra given by Shiva to Shukracharya to revive the dead?Asked 5 years, 4 months ago Modified 5 years ago

(14)Are any boons/curses issued in Rig Veda?Asked 5 years, 6 months ago, Modified 5 years, 6 months ago

This is clearly a serial unupvote attack - it needs to be investigated.  There is a clear sectarian pattern in the majority of unupvotes. three possibilities:

(1) If one user is systematically retracting his legitimate upvotes

(2) A group of users are coordinating unupvoting their legitimate upvotes

(3) **somebody has figured out how to retract ANY upvote and is planning to drain all my votes steadily.**

I hope moderators understand how unfair it is to me if all they are going to do is to wring their hands and say they can't do anything.

Comment: Opened a Code-of-conduct violation ticket 112311 with SE

Comment: why don't the downvoters record their objections under their handle instead of hiding in anonymity?  Looks like they want to maintain the "combat" tone of HSE that has existed from the beginning, but are not willing to sign their name to it.